# X-WP-Nonce is not validating and returning 403 rest_cookie_invalid_nonce

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

After researching several times I am unable to resolve this issue while authenticating nonce as per WordPress API Handbook I am still having 403 error

And I don't want to use any 3rd party plugin like JWT Authentication Plugin

please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

I am using ***"@supercharge/sttp": "^1.3.0"*** wrapper lib of Axios performing the following task

package.json

```
"@supercharge/sttp": "^1.3.0",
```

single.php

```
<div data-nonce="<?php wp_create_nonce('wp_rest') ?>" id="root"></div>
```

index.js

```
const el = document.getElementById("root");
export const nonce = el.getAttribute('data-nonce');
```

api.js

```
import { nonce } from '../index';

export const API_URL = 'https://localhost:3000/wp-json/wpplugin/v1';

export const setCurrentBid = async ( id, collection ) => {
    return await Sttp
        .withHeaders({ 'X-WP-Nonce': dataNonce })
        .withPayload( collection )
        .post(API_URL + '/items/' + id + '/data');
};
```

According to the WordPress API Handbook if I send ***'X-WP-Nonce'*** then I don't need to verify in my WordPress API Endpoint.

All the fuss is to use ***wp_get_current_user()*** in my endpoints

```
public function update_item_collection_data_callback( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
        $params = $request->get_params();
        $j = $request->get_json_params();

        $record = wp_get_current_user();

        return new WP_REST_Response($record, 200);
    }
```

Response

```
{
    "code":"rest_cookie_invalid_nonce",
    "message":"Cookie check failed",
    "data":{"status":403}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was silly, everything is right except, I should have logged out and then log in after implementing nonce authentication.

Comment: I tried it but I am still having the problem